# Search string in text file and return matching pattern

Tags: linux, shell

I've this simple issue with a text file.
I need to list and send into a file a string containing specific characters, let say "sql".
I've used grep but the issue is "grep" returns the entire line,
Below an example. I don't paste from real file because the line make more the 3000 characters, I mean I guess because I didn't count them.

But below, it's a short sample, the idea is to return just the line matching the keyword "sql"

Thank you if you can help

Below the code I used :

```
grep -Rw "sql" sql.lst

> /abc/test/01GFG.sql:/ryryutuyttuy-gjgjhhfhgdy- 
cghdgfdgfsgsgghfjfhdgfskhhjljljljljlkjljljljklj
> /abc/test/02H.sql:/ryryutuyttuy-gjgjhhfhgdy- 
cghdgfdgfsgsgghfjhghjggjgjgjgjgjgjg
 > /abc/test/03ABY.sql:/ryryutuyttuy-gjgjhhfhgdy- 
cghdgfdgfsgsgghfjhkhhkljljdjdgjdkjhfjlflfkljfljflkjf
```

What I need is return into a file the result below:

```
  /abc/test/01GFG.sql
  /abc/test/02H.sql
  /abc/test/03ABY.sql
```

Thank you in advance if you can help

Comment: why are you using  `-R` flag for a file name `sql.lst` ?

Comment: How can you get the `cghdgfdgfsgsgghfjfhdgfskhhjljljljljlkjljljljklj` in the output when it doesn't contain `sql`?

Comment: Looks like you want `awk '/sql/{print $1}' FS=:`

Answer (score 0):

After the grep, you can refine your result using the "cut" command:

```
echo "/abc/test/01GFG.sql:/ryryutuyttuy-gjgjhhfhgdy- 
cghdgfdgfsgsgghfjfhdgfskhhjljljljljlkjljljljklj
/abc/test/02H.sql:/ryryutuyttuy-gjgjhhfhgdy- 
cghdgfdgfsgsgghfjhghjggjgjgjgjgjgjg
 /abc/test/03ABY.sql:/ryryutuyttuy-gjgjhhfhgdy- 
cghdgfdgfsgsgghfjhkhhkljljdjdgjdkjhfjlflfkljfljflkjf" | grep "sql" | cut -f 1 -d:
```

Cheers

Comment: If I understand the question right, just `grep -o '.*sql'` is enough.